# How would you play AK here?

Tags: nlhe, live

Game is 1/3 NL Hold'Em at Encore Las Vegas.

**Pre-Flop:**
Hero (in late position) has Ah Kd. Raises to $10; has $450 behind. Three players call.

**Flop:**
As 4c 2c

1. Player 1 acts first. Is all-in for $60
2. Player 2 thinks for a bit (maybe 10 seconds) and calls. Has $900 behind.
3. Player 3 thinks for a couple seconds and raises to $160. Has $140 behind.

**What do you do?**

Spoiler:

> Hero chose to fold here; only in for $20 with just TPTK. What ended up happening is Player 2 pondered more and called. Turned out Player 1 had Ac 5c, Player 2 had 4d 3d, and Player 3 had Kc Jc. In the end, no straight or flush landed.

Comment: How can you come in for the first raise in late position and have 3 callers, but have position on them all? Is there a straddle?

Comment: @RaymondTimmermans Maybe other players limped in? Is that correct @Craig?

Comment: Other players limped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a pretty easy fold. You're likely up against some combination of two pair, a set, a straight and a nut flush draw.

The first player could have anything, but likely has top pair with medium kicker or a weak two pair. He could have the Ac for a blocker/backdoor draw, although I suspect player 3 is holding that card.

I'd put the second player on a draw, possibly even a gutshot draw with a pair, as he just called. If he had called sooner, I'd put him on a stronger hand, trying to trap.

The third player's raise seems to indicate strength here, so at worst, I would put him on the nut flush draw with AT+, or A3 or A5, but likely he hit his set of 2's or 4's.